# Check if an array value is set or not

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm fetching practice_string_id and program_string_id from a table

```
$project_type = DB::table('project')
              ->where('code',$asset_request->project_code)
              ->select('practice_string_id','program_string_id')
              ->first();
print_r($project_type); //output
```

Output:

> stdClass Object ( [practice_string_id] => PRACTICE0028
>   [program_string_id] => )

I want to check $project_type->program is set or not in if condition

```
if(isset($project_type->program_string_id)){
    //nothing in $project_type->program but reached here now 
}
```

I want to how to check the value is set or not in php if condition.now `if(isset($project_type->program_string_id))` is passed and if condition is working.I want to skip if condition.

Comment: So, What's the problem ?

Comment: Are you looking for [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more precise what you want to achieve?

Comment: do you mean if $project_type->program_string_id isset  in $project_type

Comment: I guess OP does not understand what `isset` nor array means.

Comment: Reading the last sentence, you want to pass the condition and skip it. I'd say don't write this condition but this is probably not what you really need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a database query, and you select the field `program_string_id`, it will be set always and any time. The question is, if there is any value. So you might want to use `empty` as check:

```
if (!empty($project_type->program_string_id)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($project_type-> program_string_id) && !empty($project_type-> program_string_id)  ) 
}
```

You have to use both `isset()` and `empty()` other wise it may throw error in some cases

Answer (score 0):

```
$project_type = DB::table('project')
              ->where('code',$asset_request->project_code)
              ->select('practice_string_id','program_string_id')
              ->first();
if(count($project_type) > 0 && $project_type != ""){

    echo $project_type->program_string_id;
}
```